# Como convertir y enviar comandos Unidode o hexdecimal en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Tengo una impresora matricial para imprimir y necesito enviar un comando de corte a la impresora desde un formulario (Windows Forms):

1. Mediante un interfaz selecciono el nombre de la impresora.
2. Tengo un textbox el cual ingreso comando en decimal para que corte papel. Por ejemplo: 27,109,0

El problema es que dicho comando (27,109,0) y se convertio en hexadecimal asi: \x1b\x6D\x0 mediante un función, pero el problema el radica que solo funciona desde código, explico:

Funcion Imprimir funcional:

```
    public void Imprimir()
    {
        string texto = "Prueba de impresion";
        texto += "\x1b\x6D\x0"; // funciona si solo excribo asi en una variable
        Imprimir(nombre_impresora, texto);
    }
```

y cuando trato de  llamar a la función de conversión el valor convertido sale asi: \\x1b\\x6D\\x0  con doble barra.

```
public void Imprimir()
    {
        string texto = "Prueba de impresion";
        texto += ValorHexadecimal("27,191,0"); // retorna \\x1b\\x6D\\x0
        Imprimir(nombre_impresora, texto);
    }
```

no funciona dado que tiene doble barra

funcion de conversion a hexadecimal:

```
public static string ValorHexadecimal(string valor)
    {
        string hex = "";
        string[] valores = valor.Split(new string[] { "," }, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string c in valores)
        {
             System.Convert.ToString(int.Parse(c), 16).ToUpper();
             hex += @"\x"+ System.Convert.ToString(int.Parse(c), 16).ToUpper();;
        }

        return hex;
    }
```

Ahora como enviar valores decimal leídos de un texto a un puerto en hexdecimal O Unicode:

P.D. 1: Equivalencias de VALORES:

Decimal       |         Unicode        |      Hexadecimal

27,109,0      |      \u001bm\0          |      \x1B\x6D\x00

P.D. 2: La funcion Imprimir es de la clase **RawPrinterHelper** y funciona

Answer (score 0):

Voy a dividir la respuesta en partes.

1. La función que tienes hace una representación textual del valor hexadecimal, pero no devuelve un *hexadecimal* como tal. (si eso existiera).
2. Lo que necesitas es una cadena que contenga los *caracteres* representados por esos valores.

   Para esto último, puedes formar un arreglo de bytes y luego *codificarlos* en una cadena de caracteres, utilizando ASCII u otro encoder. En el caso de ASCII, vamos a suponer que ya tienes un arreglo de bytes con los valores `{27,109,0}`, la codificación 
   sería algo como:

   ```
   Byte[] buf = new byte[] {27, 109, 0};
   string comando = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf);
   Imprimir(nombre_impresora, comando);
   ```

   La cadena `comando` tiene los caracteres representados por los valores decimales 27, 109 y 0, que es lo que se envía a imprimir.

Lo que te quedaría es hacer una pequeña rutina que te devuelva un array de bytes en base al texto con decimales que ingresó el usuario.